# Clear Shared Preference after Active Android onUpgrade

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

How to detect if the database version has changed and perform actions in ActiveAndroid. Similar to onUpgrade in SQLiteDatabaseHelper?

Comment: Reason for the downvote? Any link if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DatabaseHelper](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/master/src/com/activeandroid/DatabaseHelper.java) of ActiveAndroid doesn't seem to support what you're looking for. But it's on GitHub, so you can modify the library to your needs.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    executePragmas(db);
    executeCreate(db);
    executeMigrations(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

Comment: I have put a log in onUpgrade() of DatabaseHelper and changed the ActiveAndroid db version in manifest file. Not getting the log. Anything else to do apart from this?

Comment: `onUpgrade()` only gets called if there's an old database already present. If that's the case, I don't have any idea.